# JavaScript remove line in string that starts with character

Tags: javascript

How can I remove a line within a string that starts with the character `>`?

Example string:

```
   13 juli 2014 14:18:

    > dasd
    >>
```

I would like to remove the last two lines in the string above since they both start with the character `>`

Comment: that does not seem to remove the entire line

Comment: Now it does not remove anything :)

Comment: make sure you're using `replace` correctly (it returns the new string, it doesn't affect the original). see [this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/HDD6R/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use native `Array.filter` method.

Here is an example

```
var str = "13 juli 2014 14:18:\nSome\n\n> dasd\n>>";
var lines = str.split('\n');

var filterred = lines.filter(function (line) {
    return line.indexOf('>') != 0;
});

console.log(filterred); // It will remove those lines which starts with `>`.
```

Comment: Note that the filter method is ECMAScript 5.1 and upwards, so anything below IE9/FF1.5 will choke.

Comment: @shennan I know that but anyway that is a good point, I'll give +1 to your comment.